# How can I join tables with specific condition in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables in BigQuery with structure like this

```js
t1
source     code    site_id    current_stage    
1          TR      3453453    1
2          NY      3459534    3
2          PO      4456456    5
3          PO      2345345    5
3          TY      2342342    3
4          TY      9384775    2
5          TR      2345245    0

t2
source     code    site_id    expected_stage
1          TR      3453453    2
2          PO      4456456    6
3          TY      2342342    null
6          YO      7879897    4
```

I want to set `expected_stage` from table `t1` if rows have same source, code and site_id, or keep current stage as expected_stage if keys (source, code and site_id) not in table `t2`.

Expected output should be like this:

```js
expected result
source     code    site_id    current_stage   expected_stage  
1          TR      3453453    1               2          //from t2
2          NY      3459534    3               3          //same current_satge 'cuz not in t2
2          PO      4456456    5               6          //from t2
3          PO      2345345    5               5          //same current_satge 'cuz not in t2
3          TY      2342342    3               null       //from t2
4          TY      9384775    2               2          //same current_satge 'cuz not in t2
5          TR      2345245    0               0          //same current_satge 'cuz not in t2
```

My query returns `null`s when values not in `t2` because it is

```js
SELECT source, code, site_id FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 USING (source, code, site_id)
```

How can I modify it to have expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT source, code, site_id, current_stage, 
  IF(t2.source IS NULL, current_stage, expected_stage) AS expected_stage 
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 
USING (source, code, site_id)
```